# How to get a screenshot, only for a picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I used so many pictureboxs to make 1 image, now I want to take a screen of it so I can save it. I just copied this code from Msn, and edited a bit, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim myGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
Dim s As Size = PictureBox1.Size
memoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics)
Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage)
memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(PictureBox1.Location.X, PictureBox1.Location.Y, 0, 0, s)
PictureBox2.Image = memoryImage
```

Comment: You want to take a screenshot of it and or just save the picturebox image to a file? It looks like all your doing is copying the image from Picturebox1 to Picturebox2...and there's easier ways to do that.

Comment: What is the error that shows you?

Comment: Ok the thing is, I wanna take a screenshot of a specific place(The position of PictureBox 1) on my application. It doesn't show me script error, but when I debug it take screenshot of another location. @Chase Rocker

Comment: PictureBox1 contains an image, correct? You want to take a screenshot of that image and save it to a file? You don't need to take a screenshot, you can just save it to a file: `PictureBox1.Image.Save(...)`

Comment: I know and thanks for taking your time.

Please check this URL: http://i.imgur.com/YPKAUcW.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated solution:

```
    Dim s As Size = PictureBox1.Size
    Dim memoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height)
    Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage)
    Dim ScreenPos As Point = Me.PictureBox1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(ScreenPos.X, ScreenPos.Y, 0, 0, s)
    PictureBox2.Image = memoryImage
```

Comment: It's taking a picture of my application, but not for the picturebox1. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean "picture of my application"? The form? I tested this code and it worked. It captured the area of Picturebox1 (which contains 2 other picture boxes with images) and created a new image in Picturebox2 with all images combined. See this: [http://i.imgur.com/YvCoPIR.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/YvCoPIR.jpg)

Comment: I really forgot to expalin how I used a groupbox, does it matter tho? All my pictureBoxes are in that groupbox(Groupbox 1). Thanks for talking your time on my project.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code with a better solution. `Dim ScreenPos As Point = Me.PictureBox1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))` will get the exact PictureBox1 location on the form and inside any containers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim desktopSize As Size
    desktopSize = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
    Dim height As Integer = desktopSize.Height
    Dim width As Integer = desktopSize.Width
    PictureBox1.Left = 0
    PictureBox1.Top = 0
    PictureBox1.Width = width
    PictureBox1.Height = height
    PictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage 'To test that region has captured
    Dim memoryImage As Bitmap
    Dim myGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
    Dim s As Size = PictureBox1.Size
    memoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics)
    Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage)
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(PictureBox1.Location.X, PictureBox1.Location.Y, 0, 0, s)
    PictureBox2.Image = memoryImage
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it capture the screen of the windows background, not my application :(

Comment: It's giving me a black screen :(. Thanks again :)