# My code only works when I insert a random MsgBox

Tags: vb.net, screenshot, tablelayoutpanel

I've encountered a very bizarre problem when trying to get a screenshot of a TableLayoutPanel in my form.

I have this code (taken from another question ([How to get a screenshot, only for a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27339205/how-to-get-a-screenshot-only-for-a-picturebox)); code courtesy of user "Chase Rocker"):

```
    Dim s As Size = TableLayoutPanel1.Size
    Dim memoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height)
    Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage)
    Dim ScreenPos As Point = Me.TableLayoutPanel1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(ScreenPos.X, ScreenPos.Y, 0, 0, s)
    Form3.PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
    Form3.PictureBox1.BringToFront()
    Form3.PictureBox1.Image = memoryImage
```

Now, here comes my problem. This code gives me a blank picture. It takes the screenshot apparently, but all I can see is white. Now, I was trying to see if the size was correct, so I was messing with MsgBox. I add this line to the code:

```
    MsgBox("Random Message")
```

Getting

```
    Dim s As Size = TableLayoutPanel1.Size
    MsgBox("Random Message")
    Dim memoryImage = New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height)
    Dim memoryGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage)
    Dim ScreenPos As Point = Me.TableLayoutPanel1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
    memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(ScreenPos.X, ScreenPos.Y, 0, 0, s)
    Form3.PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
    Form3.PictureBox1.BringToFront()
    Form3.PictureBox1.Image = memoryImage
```

By some reason I don't know, the screenshot now works. I don't see white anymore, but the actual screenshot of the TableLayoutPanel. For me is very weird that the code only works with a MsgBox. Maybe I'm missing something. Does anyone know why this happens? Thank you!

Comment: In which event do you run this code? I hope not in constructor or Form load.

Comment: Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Just a simple click button event. The same event also fills the TableLayOutPanel with all the information.

Comment: If the fill happens in the same point where you grab the image then you have nothing in the tablelayoutpanel until you exit from the event handler. In other words, the winforms engine cannot draw anything until you exit from the event handler

Comment: It happens in the same event, yes. Does this explains why does the MsgBox makes the screenshot work though? Does the MsgBox popping out means the program finishes creating the TableLayOutPanel with all the data, and then takes the screenshot?

Comment: You can do A BeginInvoke to call the code that take your screenshot so it is invoked later in the sequence of action. It should produces the same effect as your messagebox (without messagebox)

Comment: Would `Application.DoEvents()` be a bad call here?

Comment: `I have this code...courtesy of user "Chase Rocker"` Odd that you didnt upvote his post if you find it useful.

Comment: I just added a `TableLayoutPanel1.Refresh()` after creating/adding some controls and it worked fine.  As Steve explains, Windows needs time to redraw all this new stuff.  Rather than a TImer, which just allows an interlude for Windows to redraw when it gets to it, `Refresh` will force it now.  Also,  that code is leaking a little.

Comment: I upvoted the question, not the answer. Oops, my bad. Upvoted the answer now, and thanks for the help Plutonix, like always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about if you try to make the `TableLayoutPanel` draw itself to a bitmap instead? This can be done using the [**`Control.DrawToBitmap()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Dim s As Size = TableLayoutPanel1.Size
Dim memoryImage As New Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height)

TableLayoutPanel1.DrawToBitmap(memoryImage, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), s))
Form3.PictureBox1.Image = memoryImage
```

Comment: Your code worked without the MsgBox. Thank you! Although, I'm still wondering about the MsgBox thing in my last code. I'll try other suggestion and see what I get as a result.

Comment: Very good - the TLP doesnt need to paint anymore so Refresh isnt needed either...and no more leak.

Comment: What do you mean by leaking?

Comment: @CarlosArmendia : Your code has a small memory leak because you never dispose the `Graphics` object. Wrap it in a `Using`/`End Using` block.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, thank you very much for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

If the TableLayoutPanel fill happens in the same event handler where you grab the image then Windows has not draw the UI for the elements added to the TableLayoutPanel. Only when you exit from the event handler, the winforms engine has the opportunity to draw everything.

Adding a MessageBox changes everything because calling Show (a modal call that interrupts your code and pass control back to window) allows the Winform engine to draw the pending updates and your code works.

You can add a Timer control and put the code that execute the ScreenShoot in the Timer event.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
   ......
   ' code that fills the TableLayoutPanel
   ......

   Dim tim1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
   tim1.Interval = 1
   AddHandler tim1.Tick, AddressOf tim1Ticked
   tim1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub tim1Ticked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ......
    ' Code that execute the screenshoot.
    ......

    Dim t = DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer)
    t.Stop()
End Sub
```

Comment: Then I'm curious to why `TabelLayoutPanel1.DrawToBitmap()` seems to work for the OP.

Comment: Now I'm curious too about that! Thanks you Steve for the explanation, that was what I was looking for. Do you mind answering the new question Visual Vincent and I have?

Comment: Looking at the [reference source of DrawToBitmap](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,4441da5479e7a6f8) it seems that a WM_PAINT message is sent to the underlying control, forcing the immediate repaint of the control so the following API BitBlt function has the required content to fill the bitmap. I am not very expert in this area (graphics) so perhaps there are other points to be taken in consideration, anyway it seems that DrawToBitmap is a better choice than all the code required by my answer and by the user ChaseRocker

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help and explanation Steve!

Comment: I wish I could mark two answers, since both of you helped me in different ways.

Comment: Tried looking at the reference source when I wrote the answer, but it's hard from a phone. Thanks for the info Steve.